# How to retrieve peer List in Android WifiP2pManager onPeersAvailable()?

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am trying to acess Wifdirect feature via WifiP2pManager, where I am trying to retrive peer List via onPeersAvailable() in my activity class, but could not achieve. Please suggest me how to retrive and show the avilable peer and where to code for connect. My approach is below.

Log.d is not printing its value in this method

```
@Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        peers.clear();
        peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());
        Log.e("Peer Size-* * * *", String.valueOf(peers.size())+peerList.toString());

        //((WiFiPeerListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (peers.size() == 0) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "No devices found");
            Log.e("Peer Size-","No Device Found * * * *");
            return;
        }

    }
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener,WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener {

    WifiP2pManager mManager;
    WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    View mContentView = null;
    private WifiP2pDevice device;

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
       private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
       private boolean retryChannel = false;

    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();


    TextView value;

/*
    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
               this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
           }
           */

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);




        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);


       }


        @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }
    /* unregister the broadcast receiver */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();


        manager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Discovery Initiated",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Discovery Failed : " + reasonCode,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
/*
        Button clk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showDetails);
        clk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                TextView view2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
                view2.setText(device.deviceAddress);

            }
        });
*/

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        peers.clear();
        peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());
        Log.e("Peer Size-* * * *", String.valueOf(peers.size())+peerList.toString());

        //((WiFiPeerListAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        if (peers.size() == 0) {
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "No devices found");
            Log.e("Peer Size-","No Device Found * * * *");
            return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onChannelDisconnected() {

        // we will try once more
        if (manager != null && !retryChannel) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Channel lost. Trying again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // resetData();
            retryChannel = true;
            manager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), this);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Severe! Channel is probably lost premanently. Try Disable/Re-Enable P2P.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the Broadcast Receiver

```
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    private WifiP2pManager mManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private MainActivity mActivity;
    WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener myPeerListListener;

    private List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    View mContentView = null;
    private WifiP2pDevice device;


    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel,
                                       MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.mManager = manager;
        this.mChannel = channel;
        this.mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();


        mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Channel Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Channel Not Received", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Check to see if Wi-Fi is enabled and notify appropriate activity

            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                //mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
                Log.e("WifiDIRECT-","Enabled");
            } else {
                //mActivity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                Log.e("WifiDIRECT-","Disabled");
               // mActivity.resetData();

            }
            Log.d(MainActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (mManager != null) {
                mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, myPeerListListener );
                Log.e("Peer Changed:", "Detected Peer");
            }

            // Call WifiP2pManager.requestPeers() to get a list of current peers

        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to new connection or disconnections
            if (mManager == null) {
                return;
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // Respond to this device's wifi state changing
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: Can you post the logs that you get from `onPeersAvailable`?

Comment: This method do not print any thing in console,

Answer (score 2):

Why is your call for `discoverPeers` inside `WifiDirectBroadCastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method? It doesn't make to keep calling `discoverPeers` every time an intent is fired (for which your `BroadcastReceiver` is registered).

Also, this may seem stupid but do you have any other devices running `discoverPeers` while you are trying to find them. In android, only confirmed way of making sure whether your device has Wifi-Direct enabled is to call `discoverPeers` from it (or go to `Settings->Wifi Settings->Wifi Direct-> Scan`).

So, when both the devices call their respective `discoverPeers` only then are they found in each other's `peerList` in `onPeersAvailable`.

Comment: @unrealsoul007 Are talking that in my device, wi-fi should on and in other's device hot spot should be on ? Actually, I have same issue. Even my compan'y wifi is on and when i am turning on my WI_FI I can successfully connect to it. But, from the demo app for the same peer list is not listing...what you say..why ?